# Use function in insert Statement Oracle

Tags: oracle, function, sql-insert

I am having a functions of this type:

```
 FUNCTION mfi_cust_details (vacid VARCHAR2)
      RETURN VARCHAR2
   IS
      vcustdetails   VARCHAR2 (300);
   BEGIN
      BEGIN
         SELECT    a.cust_title_code
                || ','
                || a.cust_id
                || ','
                || b.address_line1
                || ','
                || b.address_line2
                || ','
                || mfi_citycountry (b.country, b.city)
                || ','
                || b.zip
           INTO vcustdetails
           FROM tbaadm.cmg a, crmuser.address b
          WHERE TRIM (a.cif_id) = TRIM (b.orgkey)
            AND UPPER (b.addresscategory) IN ('MAILING', 'REGISTERED')
            AND cust_id IN (SELECT cust_id
                            FROM tbaadm.gam
                            WHERE acid = vacid);
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
         THEN
            vcustdetails :=
                    NULL
               || ','
               || NULL
               || ','
               || NULL
               || ','
               || NULL
               || ','
               || NULL
               || ','
               || NULL
               || ','
               || NULL;
      END;

      RETURN vcustdetails;
   END mfi_cust_details;
```

and I need to insert data from these into a table for example:

```
insert into my_table values(mfi_cust_details(myacid),anotherFunction());
```

but My procedure is not even compiling with an error:

```
 not enough values
```

is whatever I am trying to do even possible?

**EDIT**
My table definitions

```
    create table my_table cust_title_code varchar2(10),
cust_id varchar2(10),
address1 varchar2(10),
address_2 varchar2(10),
city_code varchar2(5),
country_code varchar2(5),
zip_code varchar2(10));
```

Comment: You need `INSERT INTO..SELECT` statement.

Comment: how many columns are there in MY_TABLE?,  if it's not 2 (as defined by your values statement) it won't work

Comment: @davegreen100 I am using the insert inside a cursor with other values.

Comment: Specify the columns before inserting `INSERT INTO A(col1,col2) VALUES(val1.val2)`

Comment: post the table definition for MY_TABLE

Comment: @Mihai They wnt be two columns see my table definitions.. Basically I want all the fields to be filled by one function.

Comment: So why not modify the function directly with another insert into table a blahblah

Comment: @Mihai Because the Function does not have all the values getting inserted. Some are from within the cursor.

Comment: RETURN is in exception, the function will return vcustdetails only when exception is raised

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is defined as returning one column - which is the string "value, value, value" etc (or "Null, null, null" etc) [ although i can't see the use of inserting all null values into my_table on error!].  The insert is failing because inserting into a table (without a specified column list) would default to insert all columns, in the order defined in the table, but since your function is returning one column it fails with "not enough values".

It appears you are trying to craft multiple columns into the insert statement - I not sure if there's a way to do that.

You *could* define your function as that which returns a ROWTYPE which is essentially represents one record from that table:

```
FUNCTION mfi_cust_details(vacid VARCHAR2) return my_table%ROWTYPE as 
  my_table%ROWTYPE vcustdetails;
BEGIN
  SELECT a.cust_title_code,
    a.cust_id,
    b.address_line1,
    b.address_line2,
    mfi_citycountry (b.country, b.city),
    b.zip
  INTO vcustdetails 
  FROM tbaadm.cmg a, crmuser.address b
            WHERE TRIM (a.cif_id) = TRIM (b.orgkey)
              AND UPPER (b.addresscategory) IN ('MAILING', 'REGISTERED')
              AND cust_id IN (SELECT cust_id
                              FROM tbaadm.gam
                              WHERE acid = vacid);  

  RETURN vcustdetails;
END;
```

But then you will need to do the actual insert statements inside PL/SQL blocks (ie. BEGIN/END ).

```
declare 
  my_table%ROWTYPE rec;
begin

  rec := mfi_cust_details('id');

  insert into my_table( cust_title_code, cust_id, address1, address_2, city_code, country_code, zip_code) 
  values ( rec.cust_title_code, rec.cust_id, rec.address1, rec.address_2, rec.city_code, rec.country_code, rec.zip_code );

  -- don't forget to commit;

end;
```

Comment: Will this work if I have other values that do not come from the Function? The table has more columns than returned in one function. I have another two functions to insert into the same table.

Comment: Yes, but you will need to declare separate variables and call your functions separately. Then you can just append those variables into your insert list.  Or, if the function returns one column, you can inline it directly ....  ( ...., zip, anotherFunction() );